# Cannot see my .html files under www. in Ubuntu

Tags: php, html, ubuntu

I have a website that it's working, so if I go to its address on the web, it shows up. When I connect with the FileZilla Client and go to var/www/mywebsite/html/ I cannot see the html files.

I need to change some html files, add others and so on.

Does anyone has a clue why I cannot see the files and how can I solve the issue?

Comment: maybe the html files are in a different directory, did you setup the server yourself, or are you using a hosting provider? read their support page perhaps?

Comment: What do you mean you can't see them? Do you see them if you ssh in and ls that folder? Do you get an error at all? What directory is the webservers config pointing to to serve files? Also, this probably belongs on askubuntu

Comment: your htaccess file wont change a thing for ftp access (htaccess is an apache local config file, it will only be considered by a request to the http server)

Answer (score 0):

did you verify if your ftp user had rights to your www directory? if not, you will need to go in via ssh to change file permissions.

Comment: Well, I see only parts of the site, like to folder for images, pdfs and so on, but not the html files.

Comment: most likely permissions problem. is it your server?

Comment: No, it's not mine.

Comment: you will need to contact your sys admin to get ownership or write access (or be set in the same group and give group permissions) to your website files. sorry i can,t do anything else

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are not looking at the files with the `tree view` option? You need to look at you're files with the `detail view` option. If you still can't see them I'm assuming you are in the wrong directory.

Comment: I also connected via ssh and when listing the files in terminal I can see only some configuration files like .htaccess, etc., but not the html files.